# Not make user Login after creating account

Tags: asp.net, account

I have a simple create user wizard control and It's working pretty well upto now.
The problem is I want to disable create user from logging in immediately after he create his account and I am able to do it by simply setting `DisableCreatedUser` property to true

But unfortunately when I try to refresh the page immediately after creating an account and check it shows me the user logged in.

And If user directly clicks login and checks it's giving me an error that he needs to activate his account.

So how do I disable user though he tries to refresh the page?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
                  DisableCreatedUser="True" 
                  LoginCreatedUser="False">
            <ContinueButtonStyle BorderStyle="None" CssClass="btn big" Font-Size="12px"/>
            <CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="btn big" Height="30px" 
                        Width="125px" BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="12px" />

            <WizardSteps>
                 <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                  <table>
                  <tr>
                  <td align="right">
                  <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" style="z-index:2; position:relative !important;">User Name:</asp:Label>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                              ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                              CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                     </td>
                     </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="right">
                                          <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" style="z-index:2; position:relative !important;">Password:</asp:Label>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                              ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                              CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="right">
                                          <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                              AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword" style="z-index:2; position:relative !important;">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                              ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                              ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." 
                                              ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="right">
                                          <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" style="z-index:2; position:relative !important;">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                              ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                              CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="right">
                                          <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question" style="z-index:2; position:relative !important;">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
                                              ToolTip="Security question is required." 
                                              ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="right">
                                          <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer" style="z-index:2; position:relative !important;">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                                      </td>
                                      <td>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
                                              ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                              CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UsernameLength" runat="server" 
                                      ErrorMessage="Username should be minimum 5-10 characters." 
                                      ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" 
                                      ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{5,10}$" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                              </td>
                              </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                          <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                              ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                              Display="Dynamic" 
                                              ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
                                              ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                          <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                  <td  align="center" colspan="2">
                                   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PasswordLength" runat="server"  Display="Dynamic"
                                              ErrorMessage="Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1" 
                                              ControlToValidate="Password" ValidationExpression="(?=^.{7,51}$)([A-Za-z]{1})([A-Za-z0-9!@#$%_\^\&amp;\*\-\.\?]{5,49})$" 
                                          ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                  </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                   <td  align="center" colspan="2">
                                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                                            ControlToValidate="Email"  ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid e-mail address." ValidationExpression="^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$"  ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                  </td> 
                                  </tr>
                              </table>

                               <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressUserDetails" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
                                        <ProgressTemplate>
                                            <div style="position: absolute; top: 215px; left:140px;">
                                                <img src="img/Loader.gif" alt="loading" /><br />
                                               <%-- <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; color: #000000;">Please wait...</span>--%>
                                            </div>
                                        </ProgressTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                      <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                      </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                  </WizardSteps>
              </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: I am struggling with the concept of having the user register, but then you immediately lock them out of the app.

Comment: It's just simple that I am creating new user and then it shows me user has succesfully created.Upto here everything is fine.Now When I refresh the page immediately it shows user is logged in though I have disabled his account.

Comment: Show us also the wizardsteps.

Comment: @Tim-I have updated the entire step wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution at last and it is because of this single line in my code-behind:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, False)
```

Answer (score 4):

Set [LoginCreatedUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.logincreateduser.aspx) to `false`.

From [DisableCreatedUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.disablecreateduser.aspx)  Remarks:

> When DisableCreatedUser is true, you should set the LoginCreatedUser
>   property to false so that the CreateUserWizard does not attempt to log
>   on the new user.

From [LoginCreatedUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.logincreateduser.aspx) Reamrks:

> The LoginCreatedUser property can be set to false if you want to
>   create a user account but not authenticate the account after it is
>   created. This might be useful if you are an administrator creating
>   user accounts, for example, or if there is a waiting period before
>   users can access the Web site.

Comment: @Tim-thanks for your reply as I have set that property also as in my edit.But it still shows me the user logged in.